# Output 0 if calculations is negative, else do calculations

Tags: mysql

=MAX(IF
    (Table_ExternalData_2[name]=$A$2,Table_ExternalData_2[date_booked])) - MIN(IF(Table_ExternalData_2[name]=$A$2,Table_ExternalData_2[date_booked]))

Sorry if this is such an easy question but I can't figure it out. What I'm trying to do is, if the result is negative, the output will be zero, if not then minus the columns.

```
|   Col1    |   Col2    |
|   42      |   233     |
```

If i minus 42 - 233, I will get -191.

How can I tell mysql that if the result is a negative, output 0 and if not then minus the two columns?

```
SELECT IF(Col1-Col2 =< 0, 0, Col1-Col2)
```

Is as simple as this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE WHEN (condition) THEN (true) ELSE (false) END

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Col1-Col2) =< 0 THEN 0 ELSE (Col1-Col2) END AS Num1 FROM ....
```